# SSLContext and PKCS12 keystore - works on JVM but not on Android

Tags: java, android, ssl

Android version:

```
    final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    final KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(ctx.getAssets().open("ca_cli.pkcs12"), "password".toCharArray());
    final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[] {}; }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    } }, new SecureRandom());
```

JVM version:

```
final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
final KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("ca-cli.pkcs12")), "password".toCharArray());
final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[] {
  new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return new X509Certificate[]{}; }
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] arg0, final String arg1) throws CertificateException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
  }
}, new SecureRandom());
```

The code is pretty same but JVM version works fine and Android version produces:

```
 09-16 12:24:17.024: E/AuthByPasswordLoader(14580): Got unexpected error
 09-16 12:24:17.024: E/AuthByPasswordLoader(14580):
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
  javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated:
  ssl=0x656b0148: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
 09-16 12:24:17.024: E/AuthByPasswordLoader(14580): error:14094410:SSL
  routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
  (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1290 0x40086500:0x00000003)
```

I've tried to convert PKCS12 -> BKS but it doesn't helped...

Comment: Have you checked you have added internet permission in manifest?

Comment: solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994108/android-4-0-x509keymanager-chooseclientalias-behaves-strange

Comment: @Olexandr deleted :(

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba it was a bug, introduced in Android 3.0 - here is full description https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-security-discuss/tXWPHwaQzRI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case someone face the same issue - it turned out that this is a bug, which was introduced in Android 3.0.

Quoting **Kenny Root** ([Android Security Discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-security-discuss/tXWPHwaQzRI)):

> Thanks, it looks like a bug that was introduced in Android 3.0. It will require that client key types have the same CA type. You are seeing this because your client certificate is RSA and the CA is EC.
>
> You can work around this bug for your situation by wrapping the KeyManager and intercepting calls to chooseClientAlias to add "RSA_EC" to the keyTypes.
>
> If you're interested in the particular fix that will be in a future release: https://android-review.googlesource.com/66581